# How to fix the problem with white boxes instead of text in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have come up with a problem in Unity Editor v. 2019.4.34f1 when I am not able to read the text in the editor windows. This problem occurred only in a few specific windows.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4xd0.jpg)

I was trying to restart Unity and MacOS, and also close/open window.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Graphics driver target in Unity Preferences as shown in photo.

For me, the issue was across all unity versions. So, I figured out that either it was a font issue, or graphics issue. And I started playing around.

Changing `Device to Use` to internal driver fixed the issue for me.

[image]